# How to decode XML message (that is responsed from Servlet) in Javascript Client?

Tags: javascript, java, xml, servlets

Ok, In `MyServlet.java`

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String chat=req.getParameter("chat");
    String last=req.getParameter("last");

    //String text="<message>data here</message>";--> does not work because it contains <message>
    String text="....";
    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    String xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root>"+
    "<message id=\"0\">"+
    "<user>1</user>" +
    "<text>"+ text + "</text>"+
    "<time>10:30</time>"+
    "</message>"+
    "</root>";

    resp.getWriter().println(xml);
}
```

In `ajaxchat.html`

```
//Function for handling the return of chat text
        function handleReceiveChat() {
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                var chat_div = document.getElementById('div_chat');
                var xmldoc = receiveReq.responseXML;
                var message_nodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("message"); 
                var n_messages = message_nodes.length
                for (i = 0; i < n_messages; i++) {
                    var user_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("user");
                    var text_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("text");
                    var time_node = message_nodes[i].getElementsByTagName("time");
                    chat_div.innerHTML += user_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '&nbsp;';
                    chat_div.innerHTML += '<font class="chat_time">' + time_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '</font><br />';
                    chat_div.innerHTML += text_node[0].firstChild.nodeValue + '<br />';
                    chat_div.scrollTop = chat_div.scrollHeight;
                    lastMessage = (message_nodes[i].getAttribute('id'));
                }
                mTimer = setTimeout('getChatText();',2000); //Refresh our chat in 2 seconds
            }
        }
```

The 2 above codes work fine. However, I got a serious problem. That is, if user sends a message that contains text that is similar to tag such as "`<message>`" "`</message>`", "`<user>`", "`</user>`", etc, then it doesn't work.

So my question is that:

How to decode XML message (that is responsed from Servlet) in Javascript Client?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add escape characters in you message because it is containing some predefined xml tags.

for that download this lib [unbescape](https://github.com/unbescape/unbescape/releases) (`HtmlEscape.escapeHtml4()`).

Here is modified code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {
    String chat=req.getParameter("chat");
    String last=req.getParameter("last");

    //String text="<message>data here</message>";--> does not work because it contains <message> 
    String text="....";
    text = HtmlEscape.escapeHtml4(text); // add escape characters
    resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    String xml="<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><root>"+
    "<message id=\"0\">"+ 
    "<user>1</user>" + 
    "<text>"+ text + "</text>"+
    "<time>10:30</time>"+ 
    "</message>"+ 
    "</root>"; 

    resp.getWriter().println(xml);
}
```

As you are getting this request in web browser using javascript you do not need to remove escape characters. Html does it by it self.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: But it got another problem, when user type "**<message>Text</message>**" then the message should be "**<message>Text</message>**". However, it only show "**Text**"

Comment: have you used my solution?

Comment: I did & I could not see "<message>"

Comment: what do u want to do with that <message>?

Comment: if you are sending `<message>data here</message>` in then you will receive `&lt;message&gt;data here&lt;/message&gt;`. if you want to retrieve in original data decode entities in javascript.